# Visual Studio 2012 fails building Windows Phone (8.1) application - issue with TargetVersion

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have setup MSVS2012 to build a tool for Windows phone 8.1 (BLUE). I use the same environment to build the tool for successive WDKs and was working well on my build machine till I hit the following issue with WDK 9651.12245.

1>------ Build started: Project: wifiTool, Configuration: Release ARM ------

1>c:\wdk\9651.12245_blue\Windows Kits\8.1\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(77,5): error : Unknown or unsupported property value () for TargetVersion

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Clicking on the error line opens the file WindowsDriver.common.targets  which points to the following line in the XML file:

```
 <Error Text="Unknown or unsupported property value ($(TargetVersion)) for TargetVersion" Condition="'$(UnknownTargetVersion)' == 'true'" />
```

Sounds like the build system thinks that environment variables $(TargetVersion) is not set and/or it somehow signals ‘$(UnknownTargetVersion)' == 'true' which suggests it could not validate the target version.

The file WindowsDriver.common.targets is located in the WDK installation: C:\wdk\9651.12245_BLUE\Windows Kits\8.1\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets which contains the XML schema and it seems to have an issue with the target version invoked by the build.

I have following settings in the VS2012 project, all of which worked fine till this WDK:

```
       Configuration Properties  -> General -> Platform Toolset -> “WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1”
       Configuration Properties  -> Windows Phone -> Target Windows Phone Version -> 8.1 (greyed out selection, seems linked with (1) above)
       Configuration Properties  -> Windows Phone -> Build for Windows Phone => Yes
```

Can anyone see what's wrong ? How come the build /tool fails to pickup the configured TargetVersion ? Is there a file/location I could open and look-up/modify so that it gets the correct TargetVersion in the pre-build validation step ?

Regards,

-cdhruv

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support targeting Windows 8.1, it doesn't have a time machine to guess what an 2013 operating system looks like.  VS2013 required.  Using the WDK to build Phone apps is ... strange.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use **Visual Studio 2012** for building apps targeting **Windows Phone 8.1** since Windows Phone 8.1 SDK support only **Visual Studio 2013** starting from [Update 2](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk).